# C++/WinRT compiler can't find Platform namespace

Tags: c++-winrt

I am trying to run `cppwinrt` compiler on my existing component like this

```
cppwinrt -in Component.winmd -ref local -out Component
```

as instructed on [Kerry's blog](https://moderncpp.com/2017/11/15/cppwinrt-exe-in-the-windows-sdk/). Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
    The Component projection is incomplete. A required reference may be missing.
error 0x80004005: Unknown namespace: Platform
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the `-verbose` option to receive better diagnostics?

Comment: @IInspectable I did and cppwinrt simply list the *.winmd files it found in C:\Windows\...\WinMetadata\. Anyway, I don't think the types in `Platform` are supposed to be in some *.winmd.

Comment: The error basically means that the winmd is referring to a type that is not defined by the set of winmd files provided as input to the command (either -in or -ref). Generally speaking, `Platform` is a C++/CX specific namespace that should not appear in a winmd file. If you can share the Component.winmd somehow we can take a look.

Comment: Or, if it's easier, you could share the IDL used to generate the Component.winmd.

Comment: @RyanShepherd Well, I don't have the IDL. The WinMD was obtained from a WinRT component written in C++/CX.

Comment: @KennyKerr Please check out the original `LUwpUtilites.winmd` at https://github.com/light-tech/LUwpUtilities/releases which my component was based on. It appeared that the declaration of `public delegate void ExceptionHandler(Platform::Exception^ error);` causes `Platform::Exception` to appear in the winmd somehow.

Comment: @KennyKerr Removing that and the projection works like a charm so I believe this is an issue with C++/CX metadata generation; not cppwinrt.